# exporting signed appication package fails with: conversion to Davlik error 1

Tags: android, export, signed

I have two related apps that have suddenly thrown this error. They both compile and can be downloaded to the phone. They exported OK two days ago. Since then I have added licensing to one of the apps. In a classic example of the bread landing jam side down... when I go to do my final production export this happens!
I have tried all the usual stuff: cleaning, deleting and re-importing, searching for duplicated jar files...but nothing works.

The only thing I can think to try now is to delete the entire SDK but I thought it might be worth seeing if there is anything new on this error.

Thanks
Chris